# What is the output of np.asarray(scalar)?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, type-conversion

For a long time, I always use `np.array`, `np.asarray` and `np.asanyarray` to convert array_like list to array.

But when converting a scalar to numpy array, I know `np.atleast_1d(123)` gives rise to the right thing, `array([123])`.

But I'm confused about the output of `np.array` and `np.asarray`

```
i = 123
x = np.array(i, dtype=np.int)
print x # array(123)
print x.shape  # ()
print x.size # 0
```

Since `x.shape` indicates `x` is empty, what is `array(123)`? It's a 0-dimension array still contains `123` in its `__str__`.

A real empty array of `size=0` should be `array([])`,

```
print np.array([]).nbytes # 0
print np.array(123).nbytes # 8
print type(np.array(123)) # numpy.ndarray
```

Apparently they are different, though the size of them is both `0`.

Comment: `x.shape` indicates x **has empty shape**. `x` is a scalar, what else?

Comment: @JulienBernu, `print x` shows `array(123)`, not `array([]`), which is the regular empty array.

Comment: Guys who downvoted, please leave a comment at least. The question is not clear, or even you thought it's too simple and stupid. `x` is not a scalar, but `numpy.ndarray`.

Comment: you are confusing 'empty' and 'empty shape'. `array([]).shape = (0,)`. `x` is not empty, it is a scalar, which is also an array with empty shape.

Comment: This looks an answer. But now I'm confusing why `numpy` is designed like this, converting a scalar to something seeming useless. I never saw any application of this type of **empty-shape** array. They could have raised an exception or made it work as `np.asanyarray`.

Comment: Hi @JulienBernu  it seems no other answers. so could u make yours as one so I can accept it.

Comment: I call it a 0d array.  If you can have 1d, 2d, etc, why not 0d?  This isn't MATLAB!

Comment: @hpaulj it's `0d`, but it contains something (`print x` showing `array(123)`, looks `123` is indeed stored in `x`). Could you demonstrate any use cases of `0d` array? It brought only trouble to me. I used `np.asarray(scalar)` to convert number to array, which is in a wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see this `0d` case as a natural continuation of `nd`.  MATLAB makes 2d the lower bound.  `numpy` could have used `1d`, but instead chose `0d`.

An array consists of a data buffer, whether the value bytes are stored, a dtype (how to interpret those bytes), and `shape` (plus `strides`).  `shape` is (displayed as) a tuple.  Python allows tuples to have 0, 1, 2 or more elements, so why shouldn't shape have the same flexibility?

Look at what `atleast_1d` does

```
res = []
for ary in arys:
    ary = asanyarray(ary)
    if len(ary.shape) == 0:
        result = ary.reshape(1)
    else:
        result = ary
    res.append(result)
if len(res) == 1:
    return res[0]
else:
    return res
```

It can work with a list of inputs  (scalar, array,list etc)

```
In [374]: np.atleast_1d(np.array(1),np.array([1]),np.array([[1]]))
Out[374]: [array([1]), array([1]), array([[1]])]
```

It converts each to array (as needed) and then checks the dim (len of shape).  If 0d it reshapes it to (1,).  This reshape does not change the data buffer.  `atleast_2d` does `result = ary.reshape(1, 1)`.

You could also `ndmin`:

```
In [382]: np.array(1,ndmin=1)
Out[382]: array([1])
```

`np.array(1)` is in many ways like `np.int32(1)`. Both have `()` shape, both have methods like `sum()`.  The only obvious difference is in their print format.

I don't know of any reason to purposefully construct a 0d array.  It's just as easy to write `np.array([1])` if I really want a 1d array.  But you should know how to handle one if it comes up.  That includes using `.item()` to extract the scalar value, and indexing with `[()]`.

I've encountered it most often in SO questions about loading MATLAB files with `scipy.io.loadmat`.  Some `MATLAB` constructs are returned as 0d object arrays.

Another way of thinking about a 0d array is that it adds (or retains) the whole suit of array methods to a scalar - without having to explicitly specify the `dtype`.

I mentioned the similarity to `np.int32(1)`. I've seen it in beginner's code, but have not needed it myself.